# Pinterest: How to make the content within iframe fancybox window pinable?

Tags: iframe, fancybox, pinterest

On my website, I have a list of users. By clicking each one, a fancybox pop up window will show. Within the window, I use iframe to load a page with paintings from the user.

Is there any way to make the images in fancybox iframe pinable by clicking pinterest bookmark pin it button? Or do I have to add a pin it button to each HTML page?

Thanks,

Milo

Comment: I would say you have to add a pin it button to each HTML page because it's a separated page within an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarklet button works on the page that is currently loaded. Usually, if an iframe has changed even slightly from its original url, it is inaccessible to the parent page via javascript. The actual iframe itself has to initiate the appropriate messaging request systems.

If you can have the iframe send a message to the parent window that contains the desired images and then have the parent window add the image links to the page, that seems to be the only way to do it right now. Look into the postMessage() function.

As you asked if there is "any way" to do it, I would say yes. However, it is very ugly. Probably better to add pinit buttons to each image in the iframe. :)